# How to use dictionary parameters in Python Neo4J

Tags: python, neo4j, py2neo

I am using `py2neo` to run a Cypher query in Python. Currently, I am passing the values of `$user_id` and `$name`.

```
query = "MATCH (user:User{id:$user_id, name: $name}) MATCH (user)-[rout]->() WITH user, collect(DISTINCT {relationship: type(rout), node: endNode(rout)}) AS extended_info RETURN { user: user, extended_info: extended_info } AS result"

graph.run(query, parameters= {"user_id": 1, "name": "Vivek"}).data()
```

Instead of just passing the values, I want to pass a dictionary of key and value. Something like this:

```
{id:1, name: "Vivek"}
```

And use it directly in the query. This will provide me with the flexibility to write a single query for filtering for one or multiple properties.

```
query = "MATCH (user:User{$params}) MATCH (user)-[rout]->() WITH user, collect(DISTINCT {relationship: type(rout), node: endNode(rout)}) AS extended_info RETURN { user: user, extended_info: extended_info } AS result"

graph.run(query, parameters= {id:1, name: "Vivek"}).data()
```

Is there a way to do it using `py2neo`? Or is there any other way to write a single query for a match query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can, one solution is to build the query dynamically using string formatting:

1. First try to create a query with properties.

   ```
   query = "MATCH (u:User {{ {properties} }}) RETURN u.name"
   ```

   `{properties}` will be replaced by string formating, while the `{{ ... }}` will be converted to single brackets `{..}` during string formating.
2. Define your paramters: **warning** remember that in python, dictionnary keys must be string (well, not only, but in this case yes)

   ```
   parameters = {"id": 1, "name": "Toto"}
   ```
3. Create the properties list for py2neo:

   ```
   properties = ', '.join('{0}: ${0}'.format(n) for n in parameters)
   ```
4. Format your query:

   ```
   query2 = query.format(properties=properties)
   print(query2)
   ```

   `query2` now look like this:

   ```
   MATCH (u:User { id: $id, name: $name }) RETURN u.name
   ```
5. Finally, you can run `query2` with parameters:

   ```
   r = graph.run(query2, parameters=parameters)
   print(r.data())
   ```

Note that we could have fully formatted the string to inject the parameters there, but I prefer to let py2neo perform the necessary checks there.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It works perfectly for me.